# JCheckBox returning false when selected

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a JCheckbox on a form that I'm trying to take the value of and put into a database. This is just a fragment of the code, but if it's not enough I can just go ahead and post the whole class (it's big and messy though, but I'll see how we go).

```
// Create checkbox
JCheckBox featuredCB = new JCheckBox();
    topPanel.add(featuredCB);

//Take the value of it and put it in featuredCheck value
boolean featuredCheck = featuredCB.isSelected();
    System.out.println(featuredCheck);

submitBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == submitBT)
            {   
                idContent.setUser(userTF.getText());
                idContent.setMovie(titleTF.getText());
                idContent.setFeatured(featuredCheck);
                idContent.setRating(Integer.parseInt(ratingTF.getText()));


                if(owner.updateReview(isUpdate, idContent))
                {
                    // success
                    try {
                        MovieReviewDSC.add(idContent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // fail

                }
            }

        }
```

There are some other things in there it takes and passes through just fine, and that information shows up in the database and shows up as unchecked in my table model as well.

But I put the `System.out.println(featuredCheck);` line in to test it and each time I run this it prints false even though I checked the checkbox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never check featuredCheck's state **inside** the ActionListener, but rather before the listener on code creation, before the user's had a chance to check it. Instead, inside of the ActionListener, you're checking the state of a boolean variable, featuredCheck, and its state is not going to magically change when the check box's state changes. Fix this: check the state of the JCheckBox (not the boolean variable) where its value is needed.

so.......

```
//!! boolean featuredCheck = featuredCB.isSelected(); // ***** get rid of this variable

submitBT.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == submitBT)
        {   
            idContent.setUser(userTF.getText());
            idContent.setMovie(titleTF.getText());

            //  !!!   idContent.setFeatured(featuredCheck);  // **** no *****
            idContent.setFeatured(featuredCB.isSelected(););  // *****yes ****

            idContent.setRating(Integer.parseInt(ratingTF.getText()));
            if(owner.updateReview(isUpdate, idContent))
            {
                // success
                try {
                    MovieReviewDSC.add(idContent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else
            {
                // fail
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked, thanks a lot! I'm still learning about actionListeners and what you can and can't do in them, so I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @user3690863: it actually has little to do with ActionListener and all to do with your boolean variable not changing if the JCheckBox changes. You can fix this problem if you absolutely need the boolean value by adding an ItemListener to the JCheckBox and changing the boolean in that listener.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll keep the itemListener in mind, I think I'll need it for some radio buttons I have. I don't think I need it for this particular problem, as I really only need to know if the box is selected or not when the submit button is clicked. Thanks!